# Mjoll's Grimsever

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was just wondering what Grimsever is classified as.  Everywhere I read says its a one handed but the one I have is two handed.  There was a site that said an unofficial patch changed it into a two handed greatsword, but I don't recall downloading any unofficial patches.  Was this just an auto implement when the game updated itself?

Comment: according to the discussion page on grimsever on the skyrim wiki (not uesp), some people obtain this as a greatsword.  It could be buggy.

Comment: thank you.  at least its only a glass sword.  I ended up making one, gave it soul trap enchant, and named it soulsever.  May make another and call it grimsever if I get the right enchant.

Comment: When you tag your question, you have to make one of the tags the console you play on. Answering Skyrim questions for PC is very different than answering questions for PS3/360. That being said, wherever something says "unofficial patch" they're talking about the mods for PC.

Comment: @MarkKramer that's not how we use tags.

Comment: Then he at least has to say it in his question.

Answer (score 1):

[Grimsever](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Grimsever#Grimsever) is a one-handed sword in an unmodified game. If you have [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) version 1.2.3 or greater installed, however, it will be a two-handed weapon to match Mjoll's skills.

Answer (score 0):

It can be either a one-handed or two-handed sword according to the wiki, and the Unofficial Skyrim Patch will set it as two handed always as Mjoll is more proficient in two-handed and so this makes the most sense, although without this patch it is more likely to appear as a one-handed weapon.

Answer (score -2):

well like z said some get it as a greatsword and it could be a buggy but i think it depends on the version because three of my cousins also play two got it as a one hand and the other as two but we all got different versions